# Java Multithreading Exception Scenarios

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am a beginner and trying to learn java.I have below situation and trying to get some suggestions.
If there is an error with java multi threading, what are the steps to debug the issue?
For example: There is a instance variable where multiple threads are acting on it. Variable is not declared as volatile. As per my understanding, in this case variable will be cached in local memory of thread and read from there. This will lead to data inconsistency. How do we debug this kind of situation?
In other words, how can we find out where exactly in the code, the error is occurring?

Comment: Well that is very broad, but you can basically use your IDE and debug your code or print out messages in your program, perhaps with `System.out.print`.

Comment: Just try to print after every major code part to see where does it fail or do Exception Handling or Try catch blocks to handle it and identify the area which is messing with the code.

Comment: Try to log your action with more details what help you to figure out the error if any. if you need more info better give some code sample for your issue.

Comment: Don't allow threads to share state.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to debug in java, especially for threads, is to use [breakpoints](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/). You can, like some comments suggest, use sysout statements in your code that fire when a condition is met. In the future, try to post some short, runnable code that gives us some idea of what exact problem you are having. It is impossible to tell you how to troubleshoot something if we don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.